# Using PriorityQueue with Hystrix

Tags: java, concurrency, priority-queue, hystrix

We are using Hystrix for invocation of remote APIs and we want to replays standard LinkedBlockingQueue provided by default Hystrix Concurrency Strategy with PriorityBlockingQueue.

I was able to replace default HystrixConcurrencyStrategy and do this.

```
public class CustomConcurrencyStrategy extends HystrixConcurrencyStrategy {

    public BlockingQueue<Runnable> getBlockingQueue(int maxQueueSize) {
        return (BlockingQueue)(maxQueueSize <= 0?new SynchronousQueue(): new PriorityBlockingQueue(maxQueueSize));
}

HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerConcurrencyStrategy(customConcurrencyStrategy);
```

Priority queue need Comparable objects. I can implement this interface in my command class but unfortunately Hystrix is wrapping my command object with a lot of other objects. Some of wrapping objects are anonymous inner classes, so it is very difficult to extract command object even with reflection.

Any one knows how I can make Hystrix to work properly with PriorityBlockingQueue? Or perhaps there is different approach that will allow me prioritize my commands?